# Python Tkinter switch between two buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, button, tkinter

I am trying to switch between two buttons with tkinter.

I have two buttons which trigger the functions. With changeOne in only want to show ModusAButton and delete ModusBButton. And the opposite for `changeTwo`.

I got this error message: `_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!button2"`

Whats the correct way to do this?

```
ModusAButton = Button(root, text="ModusA")
ModusBButton = Button(root, text="ModusB")

def changeOne():
    ModusAButton.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W, padx=10,pady=10)
    ModusBButton.destroy()

def changeTwo():
    ModusBButton.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W, padx=10,pady=10)
    ModusAButton.destroy()

ChangeOneButton = Button(root, text="ChangeOne",command=changeOne)
ChangeOneButton.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W, padx=10,pady=10)

ChangeTwoButton = Button(root, text="ChangeTwo",command=changeTwo)
ChangeTwoButton.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W, padx=10,pady=10)
```

Comment: What problems are you facing?

Comment: I got this error message: _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!button2"

Comment: Have you put `from tkinter import *` at the beginning?

Comment: Add your error message to the question

Comment: Yes. Also the first click on one of the Change Buttons is working fine. But the next click on one of the change buttons causes the error message.

Comment: Once you destroy a widget, you can't call methods on it anymore.

Comment: I see, but i cant find the correct way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.destroy()` gets rid of the button altogether. To only remove it temporarily, use `grid_forget()`:

```
def changeOne():
    ModusAButton.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W, padx=10,pady=10)
    ModusBButton.grid_forget()

def changeTwo():
    ModusBButton.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W, padx=10,pady=10)
    ModusAButton.grid_forget()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thats exactly what i was searching for! Thank you very much!

Comment: @K-Doe if an answer solves your problem, you can press the green tick on it. It means that future people with your problem can see the answer more easily, as well as awarding you 2rep and the answerer 15rep.

Comment: I will, but i have to wait another 2 minutes! Thanks, and have a nice day.